# How to perform terrain correction in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, terrain

How can I perform the terrain correction as the shadows from the mountains severely affect the land use classification results. The random forest model picks the shadows as the water bodies.

Here is my script:

```js
// Filter to 2019 Landsat 8 images. 
var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-07-01', '2019-07-31'))
    .filterMetadata("CLOUD_COVER", "less_than", 15) 
    .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(ROI))
    .map(maskL8sr)
    .median()
    .clip(ROI); 

// Visualization parameter. 
var rgbVis = {min:0, max:0.3, bands:['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2']}
Map.centerObject(ROI, 10);
Map.addLayer(L8.clip(ROI), rgbVis, '2019', true)
print('Image details: 2019',L8);

///////////////////////////////////////////INDICES//////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
     
var nir = L8. select("SR_B4");
var red = L8. select("SR_B3");
var NDVI = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)).rename("NDVI");
var NDVIParams = {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ["Green","Red","blue"]};
Map.addLayer(NDVI, NDVIParams, 'NDVI image',false);

// //Calculating NDWI from median composites using NIR and Green bands as discussed by mcfeeters et al1994
var green = L8. select("SR_B2");
var NDWI = green.subtract(nir). divide(green.add(nir)).rename("NDWI");
var NDWIvisparams = {min:0 , max:1, palette:["White", "Black"]};
//Map.addLayer(NDWI, NDWIvisparams, "NDWI_image",false);

//build up indices
var swir = L8.select("SR_B5");
var NDBI = swir.subtract(nir). divide(swir).add(nir).rename("NDBI");

// bare soil indice
var BSI = L8.expression(
      '(( X + Y ) - (A + B)) /(( X + Y ) + (A + B)) ', {
        'X': L8.select("SR_B5"), //swir1
        'Y': L8.select("SR_B3"),  //red
        'A': L8.select("SR_B4"), // nir
        'B': L8.select("SR_B1"), // blue
  }).rename('BSI');

var L8 = L8.addBands(NDVI).addBands(NDWI).addBands(NDBI).addBands(BSI);

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//define the bands to be used in a classification
 var bands = ["SR_B1","SR_B3","SR_B4","SR_B5","NDWI","NDVI", "NDBI","BSI"];
 print(bands);
//print('AddedbandsImage: ',L8);
 
// merge the training smaples of different classes

var training_points = urbanPy.merge(cultivatedPy).merge(waterPy).merge(plantationPy).merge(miningQuaryPy).merge(natforestPy).merge(barrenPy).merge(rangelandsPy);

//var training_points = urbanD.merge(cultivatedD).merge(waterD).merge(plantationD).merge(miningQuaryD).merge(natforestD).merge(barrenD).merge(rangelandsD);// print(training_points),'plygon n';
 
 var colorCodes =  ['#ee260c','#f0f81e', '#18bbd0','#0a4904','#ff71fe','#08ad09','#7e4300','#f5a782'];
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
// Over lay the training points to the image

var training_data = L8.select(bands).sampleRegions({
                    collection:training_points,
                   properties: ['class'],
                  scale: 30}).randomColumn();
print('samples n =',training_data.aggregate_count('.all'));

print(training_data.first());
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// splits  training = 70% and test = 30% samples 

var trainSet = training_data.filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('random', 0.7));
var testSet = training_data.filter(ee.Filter.greaterThanOrEquals('random', 0.7));

//Print these variables to see how training and testing data used

print('trainSet n =',trainSet.aggregate_count('.all'));
print('testSet n =',testSet.aggregate_count('.all'));

/////////////////////////////////////////Random forest//////////////////////////////////////////////////

// test
   var classifierRF = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest({
          numberOfTrees: 25,
          variablesPerSplit: null,
          minLeafPopulation: 1,
          maxNodes: 1000,
          bagFraction: 0.5,
          seed: 0
      });
var classifierRF = classifierRF.train({features: trainSet,
classProperty: "class",
inputProperties: bands});

var classified_image_RF = L8.classify(classifierRF); 

Map.addLayer(classified_image_RF, {min: 1, max: 8, palette: colorCodes},
'classified imageRF', false);   // classified image_RF
```